# Can I, in UK on pre-settled status, marry non-EU citizen and live in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom

In the UK for more than a year, working full time. I am a non-EU citizen on pre-settlement status, originally came here as a depended child(over 21) of EU citizens living in the UK. I thinking about getting married to a girl from my original home country. Should we get married in the home country and get a family visa to travel with me to the UK? Is there any limitation, given that I was/am a depended on my father, EU citizen in the UK?

Thank you for all your help

Comment: Are you still dependent on your father?  Are you working or studying or doing something else?

Comment: Once I have joined him in UK, I started working and self-sufficient. I am not sure what that means in terms of my immigration status. I am still under family based permit and have received pre-settled status.

Comment: @user2288762 What is the citizenship of your intended wife?

Comment: We are both from the same country outside of EU.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.